# Как значение регистра ST0 записать в переменную?

Tags: ассемблер, float

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка. Когда с float переменной пытаюсь сделать выдает (ambiguous operand size for 'fstp'). Если пытаюсь использовать long double то пишет (operand type mismatch for `fstp').

```
float f
asm(
    ".intel_syntax noprefix\n"

    "FINIT\n"
    "fld st(0)\n"
    "fstp dword [%0]\n"

    ".att_syntax prefix\n"
    :"=r"(f)
    :
    :
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь передать переменную с помощью регистра (на что указывает `"=r"(f)`). А команда `fstp` принимает в качестве аргумента только адрес памяти.

Поэтому вам необходимо исправить список параметров на `"=m"(f)`.

В придачу, вы зачем-то упомянули `f` в списке выходных параметров, хотя не модифицируете его.